# Value set according to another value in the same dictionary, python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

How would I solve this issue?

```
d = {
'a':3, 
'b':(d['a']*3)
}

print(d)
```

results in an error because I try to set the value of 'b' using the name of the dictionary, and apparently python does not like that. How would I get around this?

Also:

```
l = [[2], [(l[0][0]*2)]]

print(l)
```

has the same issue.

Comment: Given how assignment works - the RHS expression is eval'd first, and only then is the resulting object bound to the LHS -, that was to be expected : you cannot reference a name that has not been yet created in the current scope.

Comment: can you post this comment as an answer please

Comment: Done, you can delete your own repost now.

Comment: How do you know that the other key is in the dict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given how assignment works - the RHS expression is eval'd first, and only then is the resulting object bound to the LHS -, that was to be expected : you cannot reference a name that has not been yet created in the current scope.

The solutions are either to use an intermediate variable for the value you want to reuse, as explained in lambo's answer, or to first build the `dict` (or `list` or whatever) with the first key or index/value pair then build the other, ie:

```
d = {"a", 3}
d["b"] = d["a"] * 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the values to variables first:

```
x = 3
d = {'a': x, 'b': x*3}

y = 2
l = [[y], [y*2]]
```

Comment: That would certainly work, but this is just a miniature version of the whole code, and I don't think hundreds of variables would be neat, and if I had it as variables, I would not need the list anyway.